# No results from Scrapy Spider for Table Python 3.9

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Been trying to figure this out all weekend. The site I am trying to scrape is 'https://www.donlinrecano.com/Clients/wcc/Docket' and I am trying to scrape the docket no. and link. Here's the html:

```
<div class="section-body">
    <table id="DocketTable" class="table table-drc data-table table-striped dataTable no-footer">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:11%; white-space: normal; overflow: auto">
                    Date <a id="dateAsc" href="/Clients/wcc/Dockets?caseNumber=18-35672&dateAsc=true" style="color:#428bca;text-decoration:none;border-bottom:0"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a id="dateDesc" href="/Clients/wcc/Dockets?caseNumber=18-35672&dateDesc=true" style="color:#428bca;text-decoration:none;border-bottom:0"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </th>
                <th style="width:12%; white-space: normal; overflow: auto">
                    Doc&nbsp;#
                    <a id="numAsc" href="/Clients/wcc/Dockets?caseNumber=18-35672&numAsc=true" style="color:#428bca;text-decoration:none;border-bottom:0"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                    <a id="numDesc" href="/Clients/wcc/Dockets?caseNumber=18-35672&numDesc=true" style="color:#428bca;text-decoration:none;border-bottom:0"><i class="fa fa-sort-desc" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </th>
                <th style="width:77%; display: table-cell">Docket Text</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>11/20/2021</td>
                    <td>
                            <a href="/Clients/ViewDocument?dataDir=wcc&casen=18-35672&docketn=3291">3291</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        BNC Certificate of Mailing. (Related document(s):<a href='/Clients/ViewDocument?dataDir=wcc&casen=18-35672&docketn=3290'>3290</a> Notice of Filing of Official Transcript (Form)) No. of Notices: 138. Notice Date 11/20/2021. (Admin.) (Entered: 11/20/2021)

                        <a class="email-launcher" href="#" data-docid="274189"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>Email</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>11/18/2021</td>
                    <td>
                            <a href="/Clients/ViewDocument?dataDir=wcc&casen=18-35672&docketn=3290">3290</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Notice of Filing of Official Transcript as to 3289 Transcript. Parties notified (Related document(s):3289 Transcript) (Olin) (Entered: 11/18/2021)
```

Here's what I have written:

```
import scrapy

class DonlinSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   
    name='donlin'
    start_urls=['https://www.donlinrecano.com/Clients/wcc/Docket']
    def parse(self,response):
        for products in response.xpath('//table[@id="DocketTable"]/tbody/tr[1]'):
            
            yield {
                'link':products.xpath('//td[2]/a/@href').extract_first(),
                'docket':products.xpath('//td[2]/a/text()').extract_first(),
            }
```

I get no results...What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I try to open https://www.donlinrecano.com/Clients/wcc/Docket in the browser I'm getting a 404 error...

Comment: Samsul-You were spot on...I had the wrong URL. TY!!